# Advice on implementing low-level libraries in D (as opposed to C/C++)

Tags: performance, language-features, d, low-level

I need some advice on selecting the D programming language for a project. The project is a low-level library akin to a database with many associative containers and so forth. Hence efficiency is quite important to me.

I need to provide a C API for the library for compatibility with other languages like C++ and Python and I also anticipate that some sections might need to be written in plain C for tuning performance.

D seems very appealing for this job: Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of considering these requirements? How does the performance of D containers compare to the std::(map, vector, unordered_map, etc...), taking manual performance-tuning into account (e.g. using std::map::lower_bound for search/insert and so forth).

Comment: You'll never know without benchmarking these things for yourself. How are you going to write a "low-level" library without understanding its performance?

Comment: @Jonathan: I'm still at the speculative stage of design. I'm looking for quick viability answers before digging into benchmarks. I don't think it's a waste of time hearing what others have to say about this first. (But setting up some benchmarks is a good idea)

Comment: Regardless, you may need some aggressive performance tuning techniques like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking short term, i.e. tight deadline, get this up and running next week, or long term, i.e. early planning stages of a large multi-year project?

If you're interested in the short term, I'd recommend against D.  It's still too bleeding edge.

Long term, however, D is starting to stabilize.  Version 2 of the language will likely be stable in 6 months.  Andrei Alexandrescu is releasing a book entitled "The D Programming Language" in March, and a huge push is being made to stabilize D2 for it.

As far as pitfalls, I'd say the biggest one is that the idiomatic D way to do most things is with lots of templates, which makes it difficult to create stable ABIs for things.  It can be done, it just isn't idiomatic.  The other is that there's no good container library for version 2 of the language yet, though apparently this is being worked on.

Performance-wise, DMD, which is the reference implementation, has an old optimizer.  If you are truly obsessed with performance, this may be a problem.  GDC, a D compiler for GCC, has a better optimizer but is always a few releases behind.  LDC, a D compiler for LLVM, has a terrific optimizer, but only supports version 1 of the language.  D is, however, supposed to be as fast as C++, and D compiled with DMD really is as fast as C++ compiled with the Digital Mars C++ compiler according to benchmarks I've done.

Comment: To be honest this library is something of a huge associative container more or less like a "live" database. I actually don't need high performance for my initial applications, but I do intend to "grow" the library into a robust high-bandwidth application, so I want a relatively easy "upgrade path" so to speak. My plan was to start with some STL containers and gradually migrate to special structures that handles things like paging to disk and optimizing for cache usage at run time (these are obviously very long term). 
I could probably write some C code and link it to the D lib though...

Comment: (As an aside, I'm a huge fan of LLVM so I hope that LDC will support 2.0 some time in the near future. If I had that kind of time I'd jump in and help!)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to dsimcha's answer I would note that writing good performance apps in D requires in the first place to play nice with the GC. Garbage collection in D is not as fast as in Java or C#, so you need to know when and how to avoid or minimize it. Luckily, you can 1) make much better use of stack allocation with raii and 2) use manual memory management when required.

Here is a (somewhat old) presentation about how Tango has taken advantage of D arrays and slicing for a high-performance library, Array slicing fo' shizzle:
http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-4010965350602541568&hl=en#

google 'd conference 2007' for the slides. (I'm new here and can only post one link, sorry)

Comment: Ah yes, I do intend to use manual memory management. Thanks, the info on slices is very informative!